# NullReferenceException Error Database data to table html

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

i have this statement that highlighted after i debug the program. i don't know how to fix this can someone help me please.

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Server=LUIGEL-PC\\SQLExpress;Database=StudentInfo;Trusted_Connection=Yes"].ConnectionString;
```

is there a problem with this line? i'm connecting to a localdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line require key name of this value from web.config

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Server=LUIGEL-PC\\SQLExpress;Database=StudentInfo;Trusted_Connection=Yes"].ConnectionString;
```

As it's not found any key name `Server=LUIGEL-PC\\SQLExpress;Database=StudentInfo;Trusted_Connection=Yes` in `ConnectionStrings` node, it's throwing `NullReferenceException`

Try like this

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="myConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**C#**

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: i have this key name `"StudentInfo"` and i'm not sure if my implementation for connection string in web config is correct

Comment: can you provide screenshot of your web.config ?

Comment: @RigelKentCarbonel you key name is 'ConnectionString'. Try like this `string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: i already change that ConnectionString is there something wrong with the web.config i made?

Comment: your web config is ok. i have slightly doubt about your connection string. If your data server has username password you have to provide that else everything is ok

Comment: but the problem is that i am using a localdb and windows authentication i don't have a username and password. @AnikIslamAbhi

Comment: if you are using localdb, then you don't need it.

Comment: thanks, but i still get an error sir. i really don't understand why i am having an error.

Comment: the `nullreferebceexception` sir